# Adium + Office Communicator

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, adium

We are required to use Office Communicator at my work for instant messages.  I am currently using the multi-protocol client Adium for my other accounts (AIM, Gtalk).  I don't see a way to add an account for Office Communicator, so I'm wondering if there is any 3rd party support for this?

All of the searching I've been doing only points to running a separate application (which I already use), or to requests to add this feature to Adium.  I've haven't tracked down a 3rd party module, so I thought I would ask here if anyone knows of one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A SIPE plugin is under development. Here's a link to an Adium plugin binary: [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rlsfjr5yq8rxfx/SIPEAdiumPlugin.AdiumLibpurplePlugin%20%2864bit%29.zip)

And here's the link to the Adium issue tracking system so you can follow progress: [trac.adium.com](http://trac.adium.im/ticket/1541)

Looks like a number of people are interested and development is active.

See [comment 144](http://trac.adium.im/ticket/1541#comment:144) for plugin installation instructions.

Answer (score 4):

I am using [Adium 1.5.8](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adium/files/Adium_1.5.8.dmg/download?accel_key=67:1384325718%3ahttps%253A//adium.im/:64bc9a66%242b5e829d9872cde97cd7b5d79e1af8bb52e53cdd&click_id=8e7662e6-4c30-11e3-a7b6-0200ac1d1d9c-1&source=accel) with [SIPE Plugin 1.17.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sipe/files/sipe/) on Mac 10.8.5

1. Remove previous version of Adium installed on your mac.
2. Copy SIPE Plugin to ~/Library/Application Support/Adium 2.0/PlugIns
3. Restart Adium and account creation should list "Office Communicator"